# Что такое коллекция и что такое контейнер понятными словами. И в чём их отличия?

Tags: c++, stl

Что такое коллекция и что такое контейнер понятными словами. И в чём заключаются их различия?

Comment: гугл закрыли? https://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container

Comment: В различных ЯП терминология различается, но в  действительности контейнер и коллекция - это синонимы. В C++ устоялся термин контейнеры благодаря Александру Степанову и его STL. В двух словах контейнер - это объект, который хранит в себе объекты других типов.

Answer (score 3):

*Контейнер* - это класс, задача которого - хранить несколько объектов (обычно - неограниченное количество) определенным образом.

В стандартной библиотеке есть [несколько](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) контейнеров: `std::vector`, `std::map`, `std::list`, ...

---

Никогда не слышал, чтобы термин "коллекция" использовали в C++. В некоторых других языках ([например в Джаве](http://base.vingrad.ru/view/123--Konteyneryi-v-Java)) это слово используют вместо "контейнер".

Comment: Услышал я этот термин при обучении C++ в роликах. Автор имеет опыт в изучении Java, наверное поэтому это поэтому два языка переплелись в таких терминах.

Comment: @Алексей Имхо, если автор не один раз оговорился, а постоянно использует неправильный термин, то это кое-что говорит о качестве видео...

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, нормальный термин